# can not run vlc from shell script

Tags: nautilus-script

I am trying to develop a nautilus script which read selected filepath and en-queue in vlc player. Problem is if filename is space separated then we need to add extra '\' in file name. But when i run the vlc with filename, vlc can not read file.

When run in terminal:

```
vlc --playlist-enqueue filename\ space\ name.extension
```

it just works well

but when i try to give same command from bash file then vlc can not read file. My script works for non-space filename. What is the problem? Please help. At least give resource. I googled but can not find suitable solution.

Thanks in advance

**Edited :**
my script

```
#!/bin/sh
path=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
result=""
cnt=0
for i in $path
do
if [ $cnt -eq 0 ]
then
result=$i
else
result=$result'\ '$i
fi
cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
#vlc --playlist-enqueue "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
vlc --playlist-enqueue "$result"
```

Comment: Why don't you enclose the filename in double quotes instead of escaping the spaces? If I understood you right, that should be the solution.

Comment: Why don't you enclose the filename in double quotes instead of escaping the spaces? If I understood you right, that should be the solution.

Comment: I tried this "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" but vlc read this like this Barcelona%20-%20Panathinaikos%20%285-1%29%2015.09.2010%20all%20goals.flv%0A org name is: Barcelona - Panathinaikos (5-1) 15.09.2010 all goals.flv  and also tried "filename\ space.ext" which cause same result

Comment: The problem related to this question is very specific. Too Localized.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use the `for` construct? From my point of view there are more straight forward alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source file runs with bin/sh not bin/bash

/bin/sh and /bin/bash are not the same thing.  You lose a lot of functionality when you switch to /bin/sh, but it does protect you from some shell expansion concerns.

I would switch the shell from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` and see if that doesn't fix it.